# How to filter elements by node key in JSONPath?

Tags: jsonpath, json-path-expression

### What I want

Apply a JSONPath to given json response, to match specific elements by comparing their children's node keys with a value.

### Input

```json
{
    "data":  {
        "ticket": {
            "1": "foo",
            "2": "bar",
            "3": "baz"
        }
    }
}
```

### Output (expected)

```json
            "3": "baz"
```

### Case description

I want to apply a JSONPath expression, to filter ticket elements with ticket key greater than "2", so in this case it should match only the 3rd "baz" ticket.

*ticket keys are only integer numbers in my data*

### Code area

This matches all node keys aka ticket keys

```json
$.data.ticket.*~
```

This is a basic example of filtering

```json
$..book[?(@.price<10)]  // -> filter all books cheaper than 10
```

I am trying somehow to combine them in order to achieve the desired result

### Where I test it

https://jsonpath.com/

### References

https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

Comment: Your input isn't valid JSON. Are you missing some of it?

Comment: I updated inout json, now it's valid, I had some typo, but issue is the same

Comment: Are you able to change the JSON's structure?

Comment: @Nordeast no I just consume it.

Comment: I think you will need to do this in code. I don't believe JSON Path includes key filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with [jsonpath-plus](https://jsonpath-plus.github.io/JSONPath/docs/ts/). The site https://jsonpath.com/ uses jsonpath-plus library internally.

It has some convenient additions or elaborations not provided in the original spec of [jsonpath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).

Use the `@property` to compare the value of the key.

```
$.data.ticket[?(@property > 2)]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there anyway to include the `$3` from the expected output? In some cases you don't want to change the JSON schema.